# rxc contingency tables

Tags: ordinal-data, contingency-tables

I am trying to analyze categorical data and to construct a contingency table based on a survey data.

In the contingency table, there were 5 ordinal ratings(blank, unacceptable, below average, above average, outstanding ) and 3 categories for male, female and undisclosed.

I am trying to test if gender plays a role in the distribution of the ordinal ratings, is it wrong of me to construct the contingency table from the male, and female categories , ignoring the undisclosed category? I am trying to ask if it is wrong of me to exclude a row of the data since i am thinking there might be a possibility that it might affect the end result of the hypothesis test?

Comment: Wrong in which sense? If you're specifically interested in comparing male and female, it could make sense to compare only those. An equivalent alternative would be to do all three, and then construct a contrast for male vs female, but I'd be inclined to do the first thing.

Answer (score 1):

> blank, unacceptable, below average, above average, outstanding

It is not clear to me that `blank` really is part of an order ... so maybe that response need special treatment, but apart of that problem, I would tend to try an ordinal regression model with a factor predictor with the three levels `male, female and undisclosed`.

Then, if the real interest is in the male, female comparison, using a contrast for that comparison.

Comment: If "blank" means "undecided", then it could go between "below average" and "above average", but it depends on the context of the study (e.g. how the question was asked), and it has to be distinguishable from a non-response.